# How to scan the next line of a file of integers?

Tags: java, recursion, java.util.scanner

In my program, I am trying to use a Scanner to scan a file full of integers. This is a homework assignment asking me to write a program that shows all ways of making up a predetermined amount of money with the given coins, and the tester uses files like this.

```
// Coins available in the USA, given in cents.  Change for $1.43?
1 5 10 25 50 100
143
```

My output needs to have the very last line (the line representing the total amount of money ex: 143)
to appear like this:

```
change: 143
1 x 100 plus 1 x 25 plus 1 x 10 plus 1 x 5 plus 3 x 1
1 x 100 plus 0 x 25 plus 4 x 10 plus 0 x 5 plus 3 x 1
1 x 100 plus 0 x 25 plus 3 x 10 plus 2 x 5 plus 3 x 1
1 x 100 plus 0 x 25 plus 2 x 10 plus 4 x 5 plus 3 x 1
1 x 100 plus 0 x 25 plus 1 x 10 plus 6 x 5 plus 3 x 1
1 x 100 plus 0 x 25 plus 0 x 10 plus 8 x 5 plus 3 x 1
2 x 50 plus 1 x 25 plus 1 x 10 plus 1 x 5 plus 3 x 1
2 x 50 plus 0 x 25 plus 4 x 10 plus 0 x 5 plus 3 x 1
...
```

my struggle is that I have an initialized variable,

```
Integer change;
```

and I have it set to

```
change = input.nextLine();
```

However, I get this error message stating that it is an incompatible type requiring a String. How do I make it to where I can scan the next line and set it to an integer? Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: you have to read this `1 5 10 25 50 100` or `143`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the string to Integer `change = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());`

Comment: Thank you this appeared to have been the solution

Answer (score 0):

Is this the Scanner from Java? If so try this. . .

```
Scanner scantron = new Scanner( 'input file' );

// can be dynamically added to easier than normal arrays
ArrayList<Integer> coins = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int change;

// toggle flag for switching from coins to change
boolean flag = true; 

while(scantron.hasNextLine())
{
    // if this line has no numbers on it loop back to the start
    if(!scantron.hasNextInt()) continue; 

    // getting the first line of numbers 
    while(flag && scantron.hasNextInt()) coins.add(scantron.nextInt());

    // set the flag that the coins have been added
    flag = false;

    // if this is the first time the flag has been seen ignore this
    // otherwise the next line should have the change
    if(!flag) change = scantron.nextInt();
}
```